# Ceiling fan capacitor acceptable alternative?

Tags: ceiling-fan, capacitor

I need to replace the capacitor on my ceiling fan. It's 5 wire 4.5 microfarad 350 volts 6 microfarad 250 volts 6 microfarad 250 volts. The closest 5 wire replacement I can find is 4.5 microfarad 250 volts, not 350, but the rest is the same, 6 microfarad 250 volts 6 microfarad 250 volts.  Is this replacement acceptable? I have 120 volt supply. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The 250v cap will work on a 120v circuit. Many fans used to come with caps rated for 260v and today they have changed to 250. The higher voltage is needed to account for the peak to peak voltage what we measure is RMS or .707 of peak 1.414 of peak to peak.
So the 250v will be fine.